# Accessing variable in other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I've got 2 classes:

```
classVC: ViewController
classView: UIview
```

How can I access `navAndStatusHeight` from classVC in classView?

```
int navAndStatusHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
                         + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

Comment: is the classVIew a child view of classVC?

Comment: Yes, it is a child view

Comment: if it is child view you can access the all properties of the parent view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a child view,then declare the height as a property in parent view:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *navAndStatusHeight;
```

then access this property from your child view. (I am considering child view as subview)

If you are not  using segues,you can use NSUSerDefaults to store the int value and get it back anywhere you need.

To store an int:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:navAndStatusHeight forKey:@"navHeight"];
```

To get it back:

```
NSInteger height = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"navHeight"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the topmost ViewController from this method

```
UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

while (topController.presentedViewController) {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
}
```

and then get the navigation controller and its frame from the topmost viewcontroller.

So your code

```
int navAndStatusHeight = CGRectGetHeight(topController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame) +
                         CGRectGetHeight([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

in classView.h, declare your receiving variable as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger navAndStatusHeight;
```

then in classVC.m, if using storyboard segue, go to prepareForSegue method and:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"theSegue"]) {
        classView *cv = [segue destinationViewController];
        [cv setNavAndStatusHeight: yourValue];
}
```

if using xibs, its pretty much the same thing but with your push navigation.